# Rails: How to prevent the deletion of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model Country and therefore a table countries. The countries table act as a collection of iso country and currency codes and should never reduce there content (after I have filled it with seed data). Because Country is a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base it inherits class methods like destroy, delete_all and so forth which deletes records. I'm looking for a solution to prevent the deletion of records **at the model level**.

Ofc. I know that I can make use of the object oriented approach to solve this problem by overriding this methods (and raise for instance an error when they called), but this assumes that I have to know all the inherited methods of the base class. I would be glad if someone could offer a more elegant solution.

Comment: This post talks about doing this:  https://www.tigraine.at/2012/02/03/removing-delete-and-destroy-in-rails-models

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Maybe you should solve this problem on the database: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_locks.htm

Answer (score 14):

Taking inspiration from Mark Swardstrom answer, I propose the following that is working also on Rails > 5.0:

Within your model:

```
before_destroy :stop_destroy

def stop_destroy
  errors.add(:base, :undestroyable)
  throw :abort
end
```

The following will make all calls to `model.destroy` return `false` and your model will not be deleted.

You can argue that still, calls to `model.delete` will work, and delete your record, but since these are lower level calls this makes perfectly sense to me.

You could also delete the records directly from the database if you want, but the above solution prevents deletion from the application level, which is the right place to check that.

Rubocop checks your calls to delete or delete_all and raises a warning, so you can be 100% sure that if you call `model.delete` is because you really want it.

My solution works on latest Rails versions where you need to `throw :abort` instead of returning false.

Answer (score 4):

There's a before_destroy callback, maybe you could take advantage of that.

```
before_destroy :stop_destroy

def stop_destroy
  self.errors[:base] << "Countries cannot be deleted"
  return false
end
```

Comment: That is not triggered when 'delete' is used. Only when destroy.

Comment: Agreed this isn't a complete answer at all.

Comment: try before_destroy :stop_destroy, prepend: true

Comment: that's indeed a very good answer. I will make a new, updated answer, with more details.

Answer (score 2):

#### Rails 4+ (including Rails 6)

In our case, we wanted to prevent an object from being destroyed if it had any associated records. This would be unexpected behaviour, so we wanted an exception raised with a helpful error message.

We used the native `ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed` class with a custom message as described below.

```rb
class MyClass < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :associated_records
  before_destroy :check_if_associated_records

  private 

  def check_if_associated_records
    # set a guard clause to check whether the record is safe to destroy
    return unless associated_records.exists?
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed, 'Cannot destroy because...'
  end
end
```

##### Behaviour with `destroy` and `destroy!`

```rb
my_class = MyClass.first.destroy
# => false

my_class = MyClass.first.destroy!
# => ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed (Cannot destroy because...)
```

Note: If you have a `belongs_to` or `has_one` instead of a `has_many` association, your method will look like:

```
def check_if_associated_records
  # set a guard clause to check whether the record is safe to destroy
  return unless associated_record
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed, 'Cannot destroy because...'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 6 this is how I prevent records from being deleted.
The exception raised will roll back the transaction that is being used by ActiveRecord therefore preventing the record being deleted

```
    class MenuItem < ApplicationRecord

      after_destroy :ensure_home_page_remains

      class Error < StandardError
      end


      protected #or private whatever you need

      #Raise an error that you trap in your controller to prevent your record being deleted.
        def ensure_home_page_remains
          if menu_text == "Home"
          raise Error.new "Can't delete home page"
        end
    end
```

So the ensure_home_page_remains method raises an `MenItem::Error` that causes the transaction to be rolled back which you can trap in your controller and take whatever appropriate action you feel is necessary, normally just show the error message to the user after redirecting to somewhere. e.g.

```
      # DELETE /menu_items/1
      # DELETE /menu_items/1.json
      def destroy
        @menu_item.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to admin_menu_items_url, notice: 'Menu item was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      #Note, the rescue block is outside the destroy method
      rescue_from 'MenuItem::Error' do |exception|
        redirect_to menu_items_url, notice: exception.message
      end
private
#etc...
```