# Rails: Prevent Delete and Destroy of active record

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I need to maintain data integrity and prevent any deletions from the database.

I saw ways to prevent the destroy method, using this technic:
[Rails: How to prevent the deletion of records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280408/rails-how-to-prevent-the-deletion-of-records)

However, how can I prevent both the delete and destroy methods?

Comment: You really should be looking at how to accomplish this on the database layer if you want to guarantee that the data cannot be deleted. Create a user on your database with limited privileges and connect to the database with that user. How exactly to accomplish this depends on the RDBMS in use. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-grant.html

Comment: What do you actually try to achieve? Do you want to ensure that developers will not introduce routes to delete records into the app by accident? Or do you want to ensure that even admins with access to the production servers will not be allowed to delete these records via the console?

Comment: Mainly a developer does not accidental write code to delete. But I little hesitant to do anything on the database side, it’s a bit out of my element

Comment: If you are only worried about the ORM side you could redefine `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::DatabaseStatements#delete` (both `destroy` and `delete` will call this method to perform the actual deletion so raising an error from here would prevent destruction for all ORM objects. Now if you wanted to isolate this to only certain models that will be a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: [This Suggestion](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/53737621.html#comment-6-1) seems like it would work appropriately as a mixin on a per model basis

Comment: Is there a list of all the delete methods?  Delete, delete_all? Any others?  I assume I just define the delete method on the model and raise an error?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent records from being deleted from the database but still provide a good user experience where they can delete (hide) records I like to integrate a soft delete gem like "[discard](https://github.com/jhawthorn/discard)". What this does it adds a new column to your models with `discarded_at` and then scopes all the records where `discarded_at` is `nil`

Step 1) Add the gem

```
# Gemfile
gem 'discard', '~> 1.2'
```

Step 2)

```
bundle_install
```

Step 3)
Add the Discard include to your models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Discard::Model
  default_scope -> { kept }
  ...
end
```

Step 4) Create Migration

```
rails generate migration add_discarded_at_to_models discarded_at:datetime:index
```

Here are some basic useage

```
Model.all                       # Only kept models
Model.with_discarded            # All models
Model.with_discarded.discarded  # Only discarded models
```

I hope that this helps